# Virtualbox изменить разрешение на этапе установки

Tags: centos, macos, virtualbox

Суть такая: ставлю я centos8 и примерно половину содержимого установщика я тупо не вижу ибо разрешение 640х400 и поменять его никак... справа вижу я половину кнопки выход, и пунктов меню для настройки сети/разделов я не вижу. Как бороться с этой сатаной (Virtualbox работает на маке)

Answer (score 0):

Убедись, что в VirtualBox в настройках дисплея выбран графический контроллер VMSVGA. На начальном экране установки ОС нажми TAB и в конце строки

```
vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 quiet
```

добавь через пробел `resolution=1024x768`